# Histogram metrics extraction

Tags: python, histogram, nifti

I have a set of nifti files from which I want to generate a histogram (normalized by the number of bins and binwidth) and to extract metrics from the histogram to a .csv file using python. For example:

[image]

I want to extract the correspondent value of:

Red - peak width (difference between 5th and 95th percentile)

green - peak value

blue - median

pink - peak height

histogram range: [0,1]

Is there any easy and automatic way to perform this analysis in python?

Comment: Are you able to read the contents of such a file and get all the values in Python?

Comment: can you define nifti format? and give us a minimal reproducing example?